# How can I assign audio sound from audioclip array to Gameobject array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a array of Gameobjects of name DropObjects of size 12 and other array of AudioClips of size 12 for storing sound clips in it.
Every GameObject (in DropObjects) has AudioSource component attached to it.
I want that audio Sound from audioclip array will store in elements of DropObjects Array.
I tired my best to do it but couldn't do it until then.
If anyone will help me to do it.

Comment: Why not to use a dictionary?

Comment: @AdrianEfford probably because a `Dictionary` by default is not serialized and exposed in the Unity Inspector so you wouldn't be able to assign references to it

Answer (score 0):

So as it sounds what you have is

```
public GameObject[] DropObjects; // 12 elements
public AudioClip[] AudioClips; // 12 elements
```

So why not simply to

```
for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    DropObjects[i].GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = AudioClips[i];
}
```

if you directly would use the correct type you could skip the `GetComponent`:

```
public AudioSource[] DropObjects; // 12 elements
```

and

```
for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    DropObjects[i].clip = AudioClips[i];
}
```

---

As better alternative in my opinion there are fancy Assets like e.g. [SerializableDictionary](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/serializabledictionary-90477) which allows you tu use a proper dictionary for referencing pairs of a `GameObject` and according `AudioClip` coupled together so you would do something like e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class GameObjectToAudioClipDictionary : SerializableDictionary<GameObject, AudioClip> {}

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GameObjectToAudioClipDictionary))]
public class GameObjectToAudioClipDictionaryDrawer : SerializableDictionaryPropertyDrawer {}

#endif
```

And then in your script

```
public GameObjectToAudioClipDictionary dropObjectToAudioClip;

private void Awake ()
{
    foreach(var kvp in dropObjectToAudioClip)
    {
        kvp.Key.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = kvp.Value;
    }
}
```

or again directly use `AudioSource` instead of `GameObject` ;)

Comment: Thanks very much Adrian Efford .This information was really helpful for me.